# Align an "equation" environment with an "align" environment in blocks in beamer

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, block

I have a frame here:

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Susceptibilities}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{block}{\textit{Ab-initio} Susceptibility}
  \begin{equation*}
    \chi(\omega) = \frac{\mathcal{F}\left\{\mu(t)\right\}(\omega)}{\mathcal{F}\left\{E(t)\right\}(\omega)}
  \end{equation*}
  \end{block}
  \column{.5\textwidth}
  \begin{block}{Perturbative Susceptibility}
  \begin{align*}
    \chi(\omega) =& \chi^{(1)}(\omega) + \chi^{(2)}(\omega)E(\omega) \\
    &+ \chi^{(3)}(\omega)\left| E(\omega) \right|^2 + \dots
  \end{align*}
  \end{block}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Where on the left I have an `equation` environment, and on the right, I have an `align` environment.  I want these two to take up the same amount of vertical space so that the blocks are the same vertical height on the page.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The beamer-wise solution is just to use the `[t]` option for columns. @samcarter also pointed this out in a comment.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,lmodern}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Susceptibilities}
  \begin{columns}[t]
    \column{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{block}{\textit{Ab-initio} Susceptibility}
  \begin{equation*}
    \chi(\omega) = \frac{\mathcal{F}\left\{\mu(t)\right\}(\omega)}{\mathcal{F}\left\{E(t)\right\}(\omega)}
  \end{equation*}
  \end{block}
  \column{.5\textwidth}
  \begin{block}{Perturbative Susceptibility}
  \begin{align*}
    \chi(\omega) &= \chi^{(1)}(\omega) + \chi^{(2)}(\omega)E(\omega) \\
    &\phantom{=}+ \chi^{(3)}(\omega)\left| E(\omega) \right|^2 + \dots
  \end{align*}
  \end{block}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the `align`, since it's best suited for many equations to be aligned. I opted for an `equation*` and a `split` (see `amsmath` documentation).

Also: **do not use `left` and `right` unless it is really necessary:** they introduce some extra spaces and usually are too big for the task. In this case you don't need them at all, in other cases you could manually scale the delimiters with a `bigl`-`bigr` or something like that.

Basically what I did is create a new environment (`myblock`) which constructs a top-aligned `minipage` 45% the width of the page, and then starts the block.

```
   \documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newenvironment{myblock}[1]{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}\begin{block}{#1}}{\end{block}\end{minipage}}  
    \begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Susceptibilities}  
    \begin{myblock}{\textit{Ab-initio} Susceptibility}
  \begin{equation*}
    \chi(\omega) = \frac{\mathcal{F} \{\mu(t)\}(\omega)}{\mathcal{F}\{E(t)\}(\omega)}
  \end{equation*}
  \end{myblock}
  \begin{myblock}{Perturbative Susceptibility}
  \begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
    \chi(\omega) =& \chi^{(1)}(\omega) + \chi^{(2)}(\omega)E(\omega) \\
    &+ \chi^{(3)}(\omega)\lvert E(\omega) \rvert^2 + \dots
    \end{split}
  \end{equation*}
  \end{myblock}
\end{frame}
     \end{document}
```

With outcome:

[image]

Also I propose this alignment which is more usual and appealing (to me):

```
   \documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newenvironment{myblock}[1]{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}\begin{block}{#1}}{\end{block}\end{minipage}}  
    \begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Susceptibilities}  
    \begin{myblock}{\textit{Ab-initio} Susceptibility}
  \begin{equation*}
    \chi(\omega) = \frac{\mathcal{F} \{\mu(t)\}(\omega)}{\mathcal{F}\{E(t)\}(\omega)}
  \end{equation*}
  \end{myblock}
  \begin{myblock}{Perturbative Susceptibility}
  \begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
    \chi(\omega) &= \chi^{(1)}(\omega) + \chi^{(2)}(\omega)E(\omega) \\
    &{}+ \chi^{(3)}(\omega)\lvert E(\omega) \rvert^2 + \dots
    \end{split}
  \end{equation*}
  \end{myblock}
\end{frame}
     \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why surround the block with a `minipage` vs using columns?

Comment: @AndrewSpott this way you can align them at the top. I'm not familiar with the columns environment in beamer, perhaps is doable that way too, but this looked much simpler to me, since I usually think of columns as something you recurring split your text in.

Comment: Columns can also be top aligned using `[T]` or `[t]` -- but in the end there is no much difference to your solution, as beamer internally uses minipages to set the columns.